# jQuery UI Tabs - Activate event not returning `ui` in IE10 and lower

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-tabs

I am utilizing jQuery UI's [Tabs widget](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) on a page. Using the [documented `activate` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate), there should be two objects usable inside the function, `event` and `ui`. In Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Internet Explorer 11, the `ui` object is full. However, in IE10 and lower, the object is mostly blank. There are `data` attributes on my panels that are used to activate specific content in each tab that I need to access via the `ui` object, but these all fail in IE10 and lower.

Consider the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#community-areas').tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.newPanel[0].dataset.latitude);
            console.log(ui.newPanel[0].dataset.longitude);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div id="community-areas">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1" data-communityid="water" data-latitude="29.266" data-longitude="-81.1379"></div>
    <div id="tab-2" data-communityid="break" data-latitude="29.0516" data-longitude="-81.029"></div>
</div>
```

In Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE11, this code will succesfully log the latitude and longitude. However, in IE10 and below, the follow error shows up in the console:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'latitude' of undefined or null
>   reference

Adding a `console.log(JSON.stringify(ui));` for IE (since IE doesn't allow you to traverse an object in the console), it outputs:

```
{"oldTab":{"0":{},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"length":5,"prevObject":{"0":{},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},"context":{},"selector":"ol,ul"},"context":{}},"context":{},"selector":"> li:has(a[href])"},"context":{}},"oldPanel":{"length":0,"prevObject":{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},"context":{},"selector":"#tab-2"},"newTab":{"0":{},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},"context":{}},"newPanel":{"0":{},"length":1,"prevObject":{"0":{},"context":{},"length":1},"context":{},"selector":"#tab-1"}}
```

Has anyone seen this behavior and know how to work around it?

I apologize if there is another question similar to this. Google searches with "ui" in them obscured the results since "ui" is in "jQuery UI".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dataset` property is supported only from IE >= 11, for older version support use jQuery `data` instead.

Ref: http://caniuse.com/dataset

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#community-areas').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            console.log($(ui.newPanel[0]).data('latitude'));
            console.log($(ui.newPanel[0]).data('longitude'));
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Xzm8K/1/

Comment: Thank you! jQuery's `data` did the trick. Not sure how I overlooked that.